# PNG files binder software

Tags: c#, php, sqlite, png, blob

I'm looking for a way to compress several hundreds of PNG files into one big file and use it like a database, exemple "Get picture number X". I need it to be fast and use the less possible amount of disk space. I've tried SQLite with blob so far and it ends up using 27% more space then the PNG files actualy uses on the disk. It also needs to be compatible with C# and PHP.

Thanks a lot

Comment: What are your other requirements for managing the images? How do you delete them? Why not just store the database files names in a DB table and keep the files themselves on disk?

Comment: Every solution I can think of will end up taking up additional space for metadata (e.g. image indexing and such).

Comment: The image format PNG is already compressed, without losing some quality or crushing them (http://www.graphics.com/modules.php?name=Sections&op=viewarticle&artid=756) you will not be able to shrink the size.

Comment: Lawrence, I think they meant the least possible overhead beyond the raw file size.

Comment: @jmacinnes I need it to be manageable like a database, but optimzed for image files. As I said, I tried a DB file with SQLite but it's just too greedy on disk space.

Comment: You mentioned that you actually stored the image in a SQLite blob column. I am suggesting just storing the file name in a varchar column and leaving the images themselves on disk.

Comment: ∑(all files) + (metadata about files) will be greater than ∑(all files) unless you can compress. PNGs don't compress well, because they've already been compressed well.

Comment: The problem is not having some metadata, the problem is having A LOT of metadata. I have converted 30 000K pdf documents into PNG having each almost 500 pages each ( 1 PNG for each page ) so that makes a lot of PNG files. I need to bind each pages of a document together, but I want to avoid having too much metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I really wanted to do this, I'd put all the files in a Zip package.

I'd go for a "store" level, since it won't compress much, but it would have the files in a single file, with an internal "file structure" I can use to keep track of which means what, and there are libraries for dealing with Zip packages for both PHP and .NET.

(But actually, I'd probably just put them as blobs in database and not worry much about that 27% diskspace unless we're talking several gigs here).

Comment: And even several GiB are probably not that much a deal nowadays.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, we tried the zip package. It was interesting but to slow for what we want to do with our files. We have 40 gigs of files on a server which is almost full, so that makes the 27% a big deal.

Comment: Wait, @ElCapitaine, your problem is that you're out of disk space? Buy another disk! $30-40 to double your storage, or wait a few months and 1TB drives will be back around $100. The time you're spending to build an unorthodox compression scheme is costing you way more just buying more storage would.

Comment: I don't think there's anything on the market that does exactly what I want, with the speed I want, but this was the best answer I could get so I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks to you guys for taking some time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but was too long for a comment.

Firstly, I'll give you the benefit of the doubt that you have good reasons for wanting to do this, but frankly it's pretty hard to imagine such a scenario. "Several hundreds" of PNG files really isn't very many. Even in the worst case you're talking about, what, a couple gigabytes? Pennies worth of storage (floods in Thailand notwithstanding).

Secondly, use [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/). It's the *de facto* gold standard of PNG compression. Since you say your images were converted from PDFs I'm assuming they're not optimal, and running them through pngcrush might eliminate the need for further compression shenanigans.

Thirdly, make sure you're not storing more than you need. Can you reduce the size (pixel height/width, I mean) of the images, or drop the color depth? How important is image quality?

Lastly, @JonHanna gets it right--putting them all in a compressed file is going to get you the best results in terms of compression. If you're not worried about performance, go ahead and try the highest compression settings, but you may find that it doesn't make much difference since, as he mentions, already-compressed PNGs won't compress much more.

Lastly+1, you might want to check out [DjVu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Djvu)--it's a free standard, developed by AT&T, designed specifically for compressing scanned documents (which should translate pretty well to converted PDFs). I haven't used it, but it's out there.